# iptables-save syntax

Tags: iptables, scripting, linux-networking

My goal is to automate my iptables config, so while analyzing my current iptables rules setup on my local box for reference I get the following when using `iptables-save > ./iptables.save; cat ./iptables.save`

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Fri Aug 14 14:33:13 2015
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [32:10397]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
...<SNIP>...
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
...
```

What is the significance of `:DOCKER - [0:0]` and what does `-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER` translate to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what you're asking, but there's an attempt at an aswer.

`DOCKER` is the name of a chain (in the `nat` table).  `:DOCKER - [0:0]` is simply the syntax that `iptables-save` uses to indicate that there exists a user-defined chain.  There are three fields:

```
:<NAME> <DEFAULT_POLICY> [<PACKET_COUNT>:<BYTE_COUNT>]
```

Where `<NAME>` is the name of the chain, `<DEFAULT_POLICY>` is the default policy for built-in chains (like `INPUT`), and the numbers in brackets are the number of packets and bytes that have passed through the chain.

This rule:

```
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
```

Says, "for any packets that are destined for this host, pass them through the `DOCKER` chain".